# getting java.lang.OutOfMemory error with my prefix expression evaluator

Tags: java, stack, prefix, evaluator

Below i have the code for evaluating a prefix expression. I first read the expression into inputArray which allows me to read from right to left, then use evaluationArray to do the operations. I get out of memory error on this line: evaluationStack.push(number);
I have no idea why this is happening. any help would be greatly appreciated.

import java.util.*;

```
public class PrefixEvaluator 
{
    //evaluates a prefix expression
    public static int evaluate(String input)
    {
        int number, leftOperand, rightOperand, result;
        char operator;
        String inputToken = null;

        //create input stack
        Stack<String> inputStack = new Stack<String>();
        //create an integer stack
        Stack<Integer> evaluationStack = new Stack<Integer>();


        //create string tokenizer containing input string
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);

        //read string into a stack
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            inputToken = tokenizer.nextToken(); //get next token
                inputStack.push(inputToken);   //push token     
        }


        while (inputStack.isEmpty() != true)
        {      
           //System.out.println(inputStack.pop());

            if (isNumber(inputToken))
            {
                number = Integer.parseInt(inputToken);
                evaluationStack.push(number);
            }
            else                         //if token is operator
            {
                operator = inputToken.charAt(0);   //get operator
                rightOperand = evaluationStack.pop();
                leftOperand  = evaluationStack.pop();
                result = evaluation(operator, leftOperand, rightOperand);
                evaluationStack.push(result);
            }
        }
        return evaluationStack.pop();
    }

    //tests whether token is a number
    private static boolean isNumber(String token)
    {
        char first = token.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isDigit(first))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    //perform an operation on two operands
    private static int evaluation(char operator, int leftOperand, int rightOperand)
    {
        if (operator == '+')
            return leftOperand + rightOperand;
        else if (operator == '-')
            return leftOperand - rightOperand;
        else if (operator == '*')
            return leftOperand * rightOperand;
        else if (operator == '%')
            return leftOperand % rightOperand;
        else
            return leftOperand / rightOperand;

    }


    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        evaluate("* 4 - 165 235");
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in you debugger and you should see one of your collections is growing much larger than you expect.  I also suggest you find the simplest tests case which cases this error.

Comment: In the second while the only pop operation on the inputStack is commented out and there are not 'breaks' which means that the while loop goes one for ever! So the out of memory as i.e. you keep pushing elements  in evaluationStack until you don't have memory left.

Comment: To be more concrete this certainly happens once isNumber(inputToken) is true as this variable in not updated ever again once this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step through your code in your debugger you will see that this code is an infinite loop.

```
    while (inputStack.isEmpty() != true)
    {      
       //System.out.println(inputStack.pop());

        if (isNumber(inputToken))
        {
            number = Integer.parseInt(inputToken);
            evaluationStack.push(number);
```

You keep testing inputToken and adding it to a stack but you never change it so it runs until you run out of memory.

Perhaps you intended to have this at the start of the loop

```
       inputToken = inputStack.pop();
```

If you also add

```
System.out.println(evaluate("* 4 - 165 235"));
```

it prints

```
280
```

Comment: i don't understand. i pop evaluationStack in the else part

Comment: but your inputStack is never empty, thus infinite loop

Comment: oh ok, popping the stack does not empty it and the size remains constant. i get it now. thanks

Comment: @EternalPunishment you `pop()` in code which is never called because it is stuck in an infinite loop.  This really would make more sense if you used you debugger to see what it is doing.